# Laravel 5.4 getting third table information eloquent relationships

Tags: php, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.4

So there are three tables:

```html
Schema::create('files_urls', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->integer('file_id')->unsigned();
         $table->foreign('file_id')->references('id')->on('files');
         $table->string('filename');
         $table->timestamps();
        });

public function up()
    {
     Schema::create('files', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->timestamp('date');
      $table->string('name');
      $table->string('description');
      $table->integer('group_id');
      $table->timestamps();
     });
    }

Schema::create('groups', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('course_id');
            $table->timestamp('start_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('end_date')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Landing page controller looks like this:

```html
public function listFiles($id){
  $group = Group::find($id);
  $data ['gInfo'] = $group;
  $files = Group::find($id)->file;
  $data ['fInfo'] = $files;
  return view('upload.files', $data);
 }
```

loop in the blade file:

```html
@foreach ($fInfo as $file)
    <tr>
     <td>{{$file->date}}</td>
     <td>{{$file->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$file->description}}</td>
     @foreach($file->file as $url)
      {{$url->file->filename}}
     @endforeach
    </tr>
   @endforeach
```

Basically, i want to print all information from the file(probably the name is not right here - should be called lesson or something). However, 1 lesson (file) can have a few names (from files_urls table). So it should print date, name, description and all names that it has in the files_urls table in one row for each lesson(file).

relationships are like this:

```html
class FilesUrl extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['file_id', 'filename'];
 
 public function file()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\File');
 }
}

public function file(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\File'); 
 }
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look as though your model relationships are set up correctly, or that you're accessing them correctly.

You can also make some efficiencies in your controller by not querying for the `Group` model twice.

I have assumed from your database schema that a `Group` has many `File`s and a `File` has many `FilesUrl`s.

```
<?php

// app/Group.php
namespace App;

class Group extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function files()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\File::class);
    }

    // ...
}

// app/File.php
namespace App;

class File extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Group::class);
    }

    public function urls()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\FilesUrl::class)
    }

    // ...
}

// app/FilesUrl.php
namespace App;

class FilesUrl extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\File::class);
    }

    // ...
}

// app/Http/Controllers/LandingPageController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LandingPageController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function listFiles($id)
    {
        $group = Group::with('files.urls')->findOrFail($id);
        return view('upload.files', compact('group'));
    }

    // ...
}

// resources/views/upload/files.blade.php
@foreach ($group->files as $file)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$file->date}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$file->description}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach($file->urls as $url)
                {{$url->filename}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
    </tr>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you, Sir. Still a long way to go for me :)